# Can you use the same generic type MULTIPLE TIMES in a generic class declaration?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to have an identity translator that would just return the type that was passed in. I have an interface:

```
 public interface IDataTranslator<TFrom, TTo>  {
        TTo Translate(TFrom fromObj);
    }
```

And I would like my class to just act like an identity translator, i.e. just return the parameter so something like this (of course this doesn't compile):

```
public class IdentityDataTranslator<T, T> : IDataTranslator<T, T> {
        public T Translate(T fromObj) {
            return fromObj;
        }
}
```

Just can't seem to get the syntax correct here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't define the second type argument on the implementing class; you already have what you need with one:

```
public class IdentityDataTranslator<T> : IDataTranslator<T, T> {
        public T Translate(T fromObj) {
            return fromObj;
        }
}
```

Comment: oh damn, knew it had to be something stupid that I was missing